# Metro Tab Control Style WPF

Tags: c#, xaml

I would like to achieve a tabcontrol Style like the one In this project (https://github.com/thielj/MetroFramework). Unfortunately the metroframework project only works for winforms.

Can someone help me to get this styled in xaml?

Would help me alot already, if I have the style for the blue/gray line separating tabitem and tabcontent.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First create two `ResourceDictionary` to store new templates, one for `TabControl` and one for `TabItem` and name them `TabControlTemplate.xaml` and `TabItemTemplate.xaml`
2. Create a copy of default templates for controls mentioned above by right clicking on `TabControl` and `TabItem` and then choosing `Edit Template > Edit a copy...`. Then choose your style names to `MetroLikeTabControl` and `MetroLikeTabItem` and set target resource dictionaries for each template. Visual studio creates a copy of that template in selected files.
3. In `TabControlTemplate.xaml` add this setter tag to control styles:

   ```
   <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{DynamicResource MetroLikeTabItem}" />
   ```
4. Then change this part of template:

   ```
   <TabPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="HeaderPanel" 
             Margin="2,2,2,0" Panel.ZIndex="1"
             Background="Transparent" IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" />
   ```

   to this new one:

   ```
   <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
         <Border BorderThickness="0 0 0 2" BorderBrush="Gray" />
         <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel" Margin="2,2,2,0" Panel.ZIndex="1"
                   Background="Transparent" IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" />
   </Grid>
   ```

   this adds a border with only bottom thickness and makes your `TabPanel`'s border overlap with `TabItem`'s border (Why only bottom border? because I'm implementing what you want when `TabControl`'s `TabStripPlacement` property is set to `Top`. You can set triggers to implement all other states.
5. In `TabItemTemlate.xaml` set a `BorderBrush = "0 0 0 2"` for element with name `innerBorder` and remove `Opacity = "0"` property.
6. Then change styles of `IsMouseOver = true`, `IsSelected = true` and `IsSelected = false (default style of a TabItem)` as desired. This is my edited trigger for Selected state that changes content of `TabItem` and color of `Border` to Blue.

   ```
   <MultiDataTrigger>
          <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                         <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true" />
                         <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Top" />
          </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
          <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1" />
          <!-- commented line below, because we don't need Select Scale behaviour in metro style anymore -->
          <!--<Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-2,-2,0" />-->
          <Setter TargetName="innerBorder" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
          <Setter TargetName="innerBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,2" />
          <Setter TargetName="innerBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#0088cc" />
          <Setter TargetName="contentPresenter" Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="#0088cc" />
          <Setter TargetName="mainBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />

   </MultiDataTrigger>
   ```

Comment: WOW, had a hard time, but got it the way like I want with the help of your example. Thank you SO much. <3

Comment: Well, after I got the style working as desired I can't add any content to Tabitems. They are just not shown.

So if I put a textbox in my tabitem it is there but invisible. Any clue what I might have done wrong? As soon as I remove the Grid part (no. 4) it works as intended, though the fancy border is gone. :)

Comment: Everything is working fine in my side. I have custom content and custom headers with no problem. Have you set any extra `Trigger` or `Setter` that might affect `Visibility` of content or changing the `Grid`'s cells position indexes?